# Difference between JPA Entity and Hibernate Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When I annotate a class with @Entity and try to resolve the dependencies, I get to choose the package between two different packages, javax.persistence.Entity and org.hibernate.annotations.Entity

The javax package is JPA's entity-annotation, but why is there a hibernate entity-annotation and difference does it have with JPA's annotation? Is it just an extension to allow more attributes to be defined?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` has some extra attributes that `javax.persistence.Entity` has not standarized. The extra features will only work if using hibernate's `AnnotationConfiguration` directly or if hibernate is the JPA provider.

<strike>from [the FAQ](https://www.hibernate.org/329.html): 
**edit:** new link [the specific question](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-HibernateAnnotationsFAQ#I_use_orghibernateannotationsEntity_and_get_an_Unknown_entity_exception):</strike>

**edit:** new link [the answer](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-HibernateAnnotationsFAQ#jive_content_id_I_use_orghibernateannotationsEntity_and_get_an_Unknown_entity_exception):

> **I use @org.hibernate.annotations.Entity and get an Unknown entity exception**
>
> Always import @javax.persistence.Entity
>
> @org.hibernate.annotations.Entity completes @javax.persistence.Entity but is not a replacement

For instance, there is an attribute called `optimisticLock`, which tells hibernate whether to use the standard *version column* or to compare all columns when updating. This behavior is not in the JPA spec, so in order to configure it, you must use hibernate specific extension found in their own annotation.

Like this:

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(optimisticLock=OptimisticLockType.ALL)
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@org.hibernate.annotations used in your project, if suppose you want to use JDBC template or ibatis we need to change the code. if we use javax.persistence there is no need to change the code. This is the main difference between org.hibernate.annotations and javax persistence

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the differences but I am sure that if you have the Hibernate jars in your classpath you are using Hibernate JPA. Hibernate provides an implementation of JPA. Even though you are using the javax.persistence package you are using Hibernate JPA.

The difference could be only in the naming. They might provide the same classes both in the Hibernate package space and the javax package space.