# Hibernate and Spring with Hibernate Annotations = "Unknown Entity..."

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have a Project with Spring and Hibernate and I want to use Hibernate Annotations (@Entitity, @MappedSuperClass) in my classes.

I have the following hibernate-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test_iep;USER=root;PASSWORD=root" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>ch.foo.enterpriseportal</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
        </value>
    </property>

    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My Person-Class which I want to persist:

```
    import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;

    @Entity
    public class Person extends Party {

private String firstName;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
} 
}
```

If I try to persist the Person-Object, I get this stacktrace:

```
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Unknown entity: ch.foo.enterpriseportal.domain.entities.party.Person; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: ch.foo.enterpriseportal.domain.entities.party.Person
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:679)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.persist(HibernateTemplate.java:793)
    at ch.foo.enterpriseportal.domain.HibernateSetupIT.testHibernateSetup(HibernateSetupIT.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: ch.foo.enterpriseportal.domain.entities.party.Person
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1494)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:531)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:808)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:782)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:786)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$21.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:796)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    ... 32 more
```

I really don't know where the problem exactly is, but I think it might be a configuration-problem.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `javax.persistence.Entity` annotation instead of `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`. `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` only provides some hibernate-specific features to an entity already annotated with `javax.persistence.Entity`.

If you really want to use the Hibernate `@Entity` annotation, use its FQN to make it clearer it's an engine-dependent annotation:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(...)
public class Person extends Party {
    //...
}
```

These questions might be useful to you:

- [Hibernate annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7723878/851811).
- [Difference between JPA Entity and Hibernate Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/955515/851811)