# What is the difference between @Entity in Hibernate and JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

When i am doing sample Hibernate standalone program, little bit confusing was created in my mind with the usage of @Entity annotation.

Here my question is, I have one persisted class with @Entity from javax.persistence package then it's working fine but when i replaced @Entity annotation with Hibernate API(i.e from org.hibernate.annotations package) then it's giving **org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.jetti.test.Employee**

Give some more explanation are highly appreciated.

Comment: This SO post explains the difference between the two annotations and why your mapping is not found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955515/difference-between-jpa-entity-and-hibernate-entity

Comment: and Hibernate Entity is deprecated so you shouldn't be using it FWIW; see javadocs rather than just using

Answer (score 5):

> @javax.persistence.Entity is still mandatory, @org.hibernate.annotations.Entity is not a replacement.

[Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-entity)

So, hibernate's `@Entity` just complements the `javax.persistence.Entity`, and gives a few more fine tuning options.

Comment: I thought Hibernate uses JPA underneath?

Comment: @hagubear JPA is a specification, and Hibernate (as several other frameworks) implements that specification. To quote [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/What_is_JPA%3F) `JPA itself is just a specification, not a product; it cannot perform persistence or anything else by itself. JPA is just a set of interfaces, and requires an implementation.`. In the context of this question, it means that Hibernate implements support for `javax.persistence.Entity`, but adds more capabilities with `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is the same between Hibernate and JPA, rather JPA is just a specification, meaning there is no implementation, and Hibernate is an implementation.

You can annotate your classes with JPA annotations, but without an implementation nothing will happen.

In an abstract way you can consider "JPA" as the guidelines.

When you use Hibernate with JPA you are actually using the Hibernate by JPA implementation. The benefit is that you can swap out Hibernate's implementation of JPA for another implementation of the JPA specification (Eclipse Link, DataNucleuse,..) else if you use directly Hibernate you cannot just switch over to another ORM.

I hope that it was helpful.

---

JPA is not an ORM implementation but is just guidelines to implement the Object Relational Mapping (ORM)  and there is no underlying code for the implementation. it will not provide any concrete functionality to your application.  Its purpose is to provide a set of rules and guidelines that can be followed by JPA implementation vendors to create an ORM implementation in a standardized manner.

Hibernate is a JPA provider. When there is new changes to the specification, hibernate would release its updated implementation for the JPA specification. Other popular JPA providers are Eclipse Link (Reference Implementation), OpenJPA, etc. [See Other provider here](http://www.javabeat.net/jpa-releases/)

`@javax.persistence.Entity` is a GuideLine for a provider that implements JPA guideline

`@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` is an implementation for a Hibernate ORM

Futhermore you can [see this other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881611/whats-the-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate)

Comment: Not getting clear view on your answer, Can you please elaborate on this - @Xstian

Answer (score 4):

The [org.hibernate.annotations.Entity](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Entity.html) annotation is deprecated and it is scheduled for deletion:

> @deprecated See individual attributes for intended replacements.  To
>   be removed in 4.1

Every attribute has a dedicated annotation (e.g. [DynamicInsert](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicInsert.html), [DynamicUpdate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicUpdate.html)) and so you should always sue the [javax.persistence.Entity](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html) alternative.